# Is it possible to print php variable withing a variable?

Tags: php

I have a very simple question. But is really making me crazy.

I have a statement say:

> example and example with one php variable like $loggedin_user_name

First of all, I want to store the above sentence in MySQL database and then take it back whenever I want to print the above statement. It seems that their is no issue.
But when I tried to print data after extracting from database it is printing the same statement. But i guess, it has to print the logged in user name instead of `$loggedin_user_name` in the above statement.

So, is it possible to print the variable within the variable? If yes, please suggest a way.

Comment: Can you give an example with simple codding?

Comment: yes! sure, just let me edit it again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf)

```
$str = "example and example with one php variable like %s";
```

Then load it from database and fill

```
$out = sprintf($str, $loggedin_user_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the same variable name, I would suggest using

```
echo str_replace($fromDb, '$variableToReplace', $variableToReplace);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match to find you variable name in string and then replace it with str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "ABC";
$bla = "$name";
echo $bla; //ABC
```

Will always be "ABC", because PHP is evaluating your variable when asigning to $bla.

You can use single-quotes to avoid that behaviour (like `$bla='$name'; //$name`) or you quote the $-sign (like `$bla="\$name"; //$name`). Then you can store your string like you wanted into your database.

But you can not (only when using eval(), wich you MUST NOT DO in good PHP-Code) build this behaviour, that php has, when printing fulltext. 
Like Mentioned in another answer, you should use printf or sprintf and replace the $loggedin_user_name with %s (for "string).

Answer (score -1):

You can use eval function, it can be used like your example:

```
$loggedin_user_name = 'bilal';
$str = "example and example with one php variable like $loggedin_user_name";

eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str;
```

Cons:

- If your str variable or string/code which you give to eval as a parameter is filled by users, this usage creates a vulnerability.
- In case of a fatal error in the evaluated code, the whole script exits.

Comment: -1 for not mentioning the downside and **encourage the use of `eval`**

Comment: You are right. Because I didn't write cons, I was like encourage the use of eval. But I was trying to say "look there is a way like this". Also, I don't think if code is created by proggrammer (which I understood from his explanation like this), it turns lead to a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Best would be to concatinate a string:

```
$exampleWithUsername = 'example' . $loggedin_user_name;

echo $exampleWithUsername;
```

'example' is a hardcoded string, but you can give it a variable containing string $example, or directly concatinate $username into $example.